# Visualizing combined Vectors

Tags: plotting, physics, vector-calculus

I'm trying to visualize a cross-section of a finite continuous solenoid's B-Field (cylindrical coordinate equations from Wikipedia). I believe I have calculated the radial and z-axis fields, but I'm having trouble combining them and visualizing them in a StreamPlot or VectorPlot. Suggestions are appreciated.

```
u0 = 4 Pi 1*^-7;
coilRadius = 0.0390;
coilLength = 0.0500;
coilCurrent = 400;
coilTurns = 500;

zp[z_] := z + coilLength/2
zm[z_] := z - coilLength/2

kp[rho_, z_] := Sqrt[(
 4 coilRadius rho)/((coilRadius + rho)^2 + zp[z]^2)]
km[rho_, z_] := Sqrt[(
 4 coilRadius rho)/((coilRadius + rho)^2 + zm[z]^2)]
h[rho_] := Sqrt[(4 coilRadius rho)/(coilRadius + rho)^2]

br[rho_, z_] := 
 1/(4 π coilLength) (coilCurrent coilTurns u0) Sqrt[coilRadius/
  rho] ((((kp[rho, z]^2 - 2) EllipticK[kp[rho, z]^2])/kp[rho, z] + (
      2 EllipticE[kp[rho, z]^2])/
      kp[rho, z]) - (((km[rho, z]^2 - 2) EllipticK[km[rho, z]^2])/
      km[rho, z] + (2 EllipticE[km[rho, z]^2])/km[rho, z]))
bz[rho_, z_] := ((coilCurrent coilTurns u0) /((4 π coilLength) Sqrt[
      coilRadius rho])) (zp[z] kp[rho, 
      z] (EllipticK[
        kp[rho, z]^2] + ((coilRadius - rho) EllipticPi[h[rho]^2, 
         kp[rho, z]^2])/(coilRadius + rho)) - 
    zm[z] km[rho, 
      z] (EllipticK[
        km[rho, z]^2] + ((coilRadius - rho) EllipticPi[h[rho]^2, 
         km[rho, z]^2])/(coilRadius + rho)))
```

Plots:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  ContourPlot[
   br[rho, z], {rho, 0, coilRadius}, {z, -coilLength/2, coilLength/2},
   PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"],

  ContourPlot[
   bz[rho, z], {rho, 0, coilRadius}, {z, -coilLength/2, coilLength/2},
   PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"],

  ContourPlot[
   Sqrt[bz[rho, z]^2 + br[rho, z]^2], {rho, 0, 
    coilRadius}, {z, -coilLength/2, coilLength/2},
   PlotRange -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
  }, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
bFieldCylin2D[r_, ζ_] = {br[r, ζ], 0, bz[r, ζ]};
bField3D[x_, y_, z_] = 
  TransformedField["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", 
   bFieldCylin2D[r, ζ], {r, th, ζ} -> {x, y, z}];

Show[
 SliceContourPlot3D[
  Sqrt[bField3D[x, y, z][[1]]^2 + bField3D[x, y, z][[2]]^2 + 
    bField3D[x, y, z][[3]]^2],
  {"XStackedPlanes", 1},
  {x, -coilRadius, coilRadius},
  {y, -coilRadius, coilRadius},
  {z, -coilLength/2, coilLength/2},
  Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"],

 VectorPlot3D[bField3D[x, y, z],
  {x, -coilRadius, coilRadius},
  {y, -coilRadius, coilRadius},
  {z, -coilLength/2, coilLength/2},
  VectorStyle -> Red, VectorScale -> Small]
 ]
```

[image]