# Setting Up Boundary Conditions for Magnetostatic PDE

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, physics, finite-element-method, boundary-condition-at-infinity

**Bug introduced in 11.2.0 and fixed in 11.3.0**

---

The system is a hollow cylinder (thin solenoid) with a current density $\text{J}$ and I'm looking to solve the magnetic potential ($\text{A}$) inside the radius of the cylinder using FEA. I'm struggling with the boundary conditions for the open ends (and in general). Suggestions are appreciated.

```
u0 = 4 Pi 1*^-7;

j = 100; (*current density parallel to z-axis*)

solution = 
 NDSolveValue[{
  -Div[(1/u0) Grad[u[r, z], {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"], 
   {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"] == NeumannValue[j, r == 1],
   DirichletCondition[u[r, z] == 0, z^2 == 1]},
  u, {r, 0, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}]

ContourPlot[solution[r, z], {r, z} ∈ solution["ElementMesh"],
  PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 19, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

To compute the magnetic density field ($\text{B}$):

```
bField = Curl[solution[r, z], {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"]
```

**Update:**

I've done additional research and the following is an approach by [FEMM](http://www.femm.info/Archives/contrib/TutorialUpdate.zip) to solve such problems. The cross section is still in cylindrical coordinates but the open boundary is spherical.

```
bound = Table[{boundRadius Sin[theta], 
    boundRadius Cos[theta]}, {theta, 0, Pi, Pi/100}];
boundIndex = Partition[Last[FindShortestTour[bound]], 2, 1];

coil = {{1, -1}, {1, 1}};
coilIndex = {{Length[bound] + 1, Length[bound] + 2}};

boundRadius = 2;
reg = ImplicitRegion[r^2 + z^2 < boundRadius^2 && r >= 0, {r, z}];

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[bound, coil], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[Join[boundIndex, coilIndex]]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];

Show[
 RegionPlot[reg, Epilog -> Point[bound], AspectRatio -> 2, 
  ImageSize -> Medium],
 bmesh["Wireframe"]
 ]
```

[image]

I need to apply the following mixed boundary condition to the spherical surface:

$\frac{1}{\mu_0}\frac{\partial A}{\partial r}+\frac{A}{\mu_0 R} = 0$

I have the following failed attempt (`NDSolveValue` spits out `bcnop` warning and the internal b.c. is ignored):

```
u0 = 4 Pi 1*^-7;
j = 100;

solution = 
 NDSolveValue[{-Div[(1/u0) Grad[u[r, z], {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"], 
              {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"] - j ==
    NeumannValue[0, r == 0] - 
    NeumannValue[u[r, z]/(boundRadius u0), r^2 + z^2 == boundRadius^2],
    DirichletCondition[u[r, z] == u0 j, r == 1 && z^2 <= 1]},
  u, {r, z} ∈ mesh,
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]

ContourPlot[solution[r, z], {r, z} ∈ solution["ElementMesh"],
  PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 19, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 AspectRatio -> 2]
```

Comment: Just a precison for beginners in magnetostatic : this problem can be solved anatically. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid)

Comment: That's what I was thinking. My message was for "visitors"

Comment: The problem of open ends (=boundaries at infinity) arrises very often in magnetostatics and electrostatics. Example : In electrostatics in 2 dimensions, on may use a conformal mapping to map infinity to finite boundaries, and then use FEM. Otherwise,  FEM solvers have special complex methods for dealing with some "infinite mesh elements" (?). I'm afraid that's not a simple affair. Would be happy to be wrong.

Comment: Do you have an example with an expected solution?

Comment: @user21 The FEA solution can be checked with my analytical solution code here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156104/visualizing-combined-vectors (the result matches the common $r = 0$ simplified equation)

Comment: @user21 The `bcnop` warning seems to be unreasonable, is it a bug?

Comment: @xzczd, no I do not think so: `Show[Graphics[
  GraphicsComplex[mesh["Coordinates"], 
   Point[Flatten[ElementIncidents[mesh["PointElements"]]]]]]]` there are no PointElements on the internal line. From a physics standpoint the wire needs to have an extension - there is no 1D wire. So I think your approach is the way to go and the fact that NDSolve warned that it could not find positions for the boundary condition is good.

Comment: Could you mention your Mathematica Version in the question ? Thanks.

Comment: OK, @xzczd there is a regression in V11.2 that triggered the message and that will need to get fixed. Never the less I think the wire should have some extension.

Comment: @user21 I don't think that the "wire" should have extension. To be confirmed by specialists. Nevertheless I will try to find a clear explanation or a link to this subject

Comment: Do you have a  link to your mix boundary condition on the potential vector ? I want to see if it is dependant of the gauge of the potential vector ( I don't obtain your boundary condition when I apply them to the analytical potential vector) Thanks

Comment: @xzczd, I just merged a fix for this problem, the next release will work as expected. Thanks for digging this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed in version 11.3:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
boundRadius = 2;
bound = Table[{boundRadius Sin[theta], 
    boundRadius Cos[theta]}, {theta, 0, Pi, Pi/100}];
boundIndex = Partition[Last[FindShortestTour[bound]], 2, 1];

coil = {{1, -1}, {1, 1}};
coilIndex = {{Length[bound] + 1, Length[bound] + 2}};

reg = ImplicitRegion[r^2 + z^2 < boundRadius^2 && r >= 0, {r, z}];

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[bound, coil], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[Join[boundIndex, coilIndex]]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];

Show[RegionPlot[reg, Epilog -> Point[bound], AspectRatio -> 2, 
  ImageSize -> Medium], bmesh["Wireframe"]]
```

[image]

```
Show[Graphics[
  GraphicsComplex[mesh["Coordinates"], 
   Point[Flatten[ElementIncidents[mesh["PointElements"]]]]]]]
```

[image]

Note, how the interior points are now (again) part of the boundary mesh. And the solution:

```
u0 = 4 Pi 1*^-7;
j = 100;

solution = 
  NDSolveValue[{-Div[(1/u0) Grad[u[r, z], {r, th, z}, 
          "Cylindrical"], {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"] - j == 
     NeumannValue[0, r == 0] - 
      NeumannValue[u[r, z]/(boundRadius u0), 
       r^2 + z^2 == boundRadius^2], 
    DirichletCondition[u[r, z] == u0 j, r == 1 && z^2 <= 1]}, 
   u, {r, z} \[Element] mesh];

ContourPlot[solution[r, z], {r, z} \[Element] solution["ElementMesh"],
  PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 19, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 AspectRatio -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Well, I'm not quite familiar with electromagnetism and it's not immediately clear to me how to compare the numeric solution with the analytic solution, but I've circumvented the `bcnop` warning anyway, so let me post an answer.

The idea is creating a very narrow slit in the domain to approximate the wire i.e. the `LineElement` in your failed attempt. Notice I've also enlarge `boundRadius` because after some trial I noticed `boundRadius = 2` is too small:

```
boundRadius = 4;
u0 = 4 Pi 1*^-7;
j = 100;

eps = 10^-4;

reg = ImplicitRegion[
   r^2 + z^2 < boundRadius^2 && r >= 0 && ! (1 - eps < r < 1 + eps && z^2 < 1), {r, z}];

solution = NDSolveValue[{-Div[(1/u0) Grad[u[r, z], {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"], {r, th, 
        z}, "Cylindrical"] - 
     j == -NeumannValue[u[r, z]/(boundRadius u0), r^2 + z^2 == boundRadius^2], 
   DirichletCondition[u[r, z] == u0 j, 1 - eps < r < 1 + eps && z^2 < 1]}, 
  u, {r, z} ∈ reg, 
  Method -> {FiniteElement, MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}]

interestedRadius = 2;
interestedreg = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   r^2 + z^2 < interestedRadius^2 && ! (1 - eps < r < 1 + eps && z^2 < 1), {r, z}];

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@PiecewiseExpand@If[r > 0, solution[r, z], solution[-r, z]], {r, z} ∈ 
  interestedreg, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, Contours -> 19]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think this is the way to go - also from a physics point of view. You may want to create the mesh manually like in the question for very 'thin' wires.

Comment: I eventually obtained a result close to your graph but when you take the Curl of `solution` to obtain the magnetic field it doesn't match the analytical solution.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with how I formed the differential equation.

Comment: @Young Er…sorry, but the $A$ i.e. `u` in your equation is a scalar, how can you calculate its `Curl`?

Comment: @xzczd It's a little bit subtle : The value u[x,y] calculated by Young is only a component of the potential *vector* (the component Aphi in cylindrical coordinate, that is to the component perpendicular to the paper). The other components are 0 in this case (because of the symetries of the problem).

Comment: It happens that this component verify exactly the Laplace equation, like a simple potential *scalar*

Comment: I'm afraid that there is a problem in the method of calculating first the potantial vector then taking the curl : The derivative of the fem solutions of the Laplace equation are not nice (in general).

Comment: @andre I think it's (at least partly) because the original `boundRadius` is too small, see my update. (I agree the low `"MeshOrder"` may have caused problem in the calculation of `Curl`. )

Comment: The use of `PiecewiseExpand` seems unnecessary; replace `Evaluate@PiecewiseExpand@If[r > 0, solution[r, z], solution[-r, z]]` by `Evaluate@solution[Abs@r, z]`

Comment: @RonaldMonson Yeah in this case `Abs` is conciser, but I'd like to point out `PiecewiseExpand@If[…]` is a more general setting: what if we need `If[r>1, …`?

Answer (score 6):

**Extended comment**

The result of the OP's code are not the same on Mathematica 11.0 and Mathematica 11.2

Here is the code I have used :

```
<<NDSolve`FEM`

bound = Table[{boundRadius Sin[theta], 
    boundRadius Cos[theta]}, {theta, 0, Pi, Pi/100}];
boundIndex = Partition[Last[FindShortestTour[bound]], 2, 1];

coil = {{1, -1}, {1, 1}};
coilIndex = {{Length[bound] + 1, Length[bound] + 2}};

boundRadius = 2;
reg = ImplicitRegion[r^2 + z^2 < boundRadius^2 && r >= 0, {r, z}];

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[bound, coil], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[Join[boundIndex, coilIndex]]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];

(*Show[
 RegionPlot[reg, Epilog -> Point[bound], AspectRatio -> 2, 
  ImageSize -> Medium],
 bmesh["Wireframe"]
 ]*)

u0 = 4 Pi 1*^-7;
j = 100;

solution = 
 NDSolveValue[{-Div[(1/u0) Grad[u[r, z], {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"], 
              {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"] - j ==
    NeumannValue[0, r == 0] - 
    NeumannValue[u[r, z]/(boundRadius u0), r^2 + z^2 == boundRadius^2],
    DirichletCondition[u[r, z] == u0 j, r == 1 && z^2 <= 1]},
  u, {r, z} \[Element] mesh,
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]

ContourPlot[solution[r, z], {r, z} \[Element] solution["ElementMesh"],
  PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 19, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 AspectRatio -> 2]
```

**Mathematica 11.2**

[image]

**Mathematica 11.0 - first evaluation (on a fresh kernel)**

It doesn't work :

> [image]

**Mathematica 11.0 - second evaluation (= reevaluation of the same code)**

[image]

**Edit**

same as before, but with `PlotPoints->50`added to `ContourPlot`:

[image]

Comment: Will the last result be improved if you add e.g. `PlotPoints->50` to `ContourPlot`?

Comment: @xzczd see my edit. Nice !

Comment: My mathematica 11.2  trial version expire **today**. I will have another 11.2 on 6 October 2017.

Comment: It helps if you define the boundRadius = 2; before the bound.

Comment: Then `Last[FindShortestTour[bound]]` works.

Comment: OK, thanks Andre (@xzczd) this is a regression in 11.2 and I'll see to get it fixed for the next release.

Comment: A precision for visitors : the comment of @user21 above (boundRadius =2 before the bound) is destinated to fix the problem of the failing first evaluation on Mathematica version 11.0

Comment: @andre, I merged a fix that will make a new release after V11.2 behave like 11.0. Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 4):

Extended comment:

Something like this

```
epsi = 10^-1;
coil = {{1 - epsi, -1}, {1 - epsi, 1}, {1 + epsi, 
    1}, {1 + epsi, -1}};
coilIndex = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}} + Length[bound];

boundRadius = 2;
reg = ImplicitRegion[r^2 + z^2 < boundRadius^2 && r >= 0, {r, z}];

Show[
 bmesh["Wireframe"],
 Graphics[{Blue, Point[{1, 0}]}],
 Graphics[
  GraphicsComplex[
   bmesh["Coordinates"], {Red, 
    Point[Flatten[ElementIncidents[bmesh["PointElements"]]]]}]]
 ]
```